# Remove HTML Elements from JQuery AJAX load() Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, response

Is there a possibility to remove specific HTML Elements from a AJAX (load) Response before placing in to the container? In this case I want to remove the "#containerTop", including content, from the response.

Response (HTML):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="containerMain">
      <div>...</div>
      <div id="containerTop">Content-to-remove-including-container-div...</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried this, without success.

```
<div id="middle"></div>
<script>
$( "#middle" ).load( "http://<URL>",
function(response, status, xhr){
$response.remove('#containerTop');
            });
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load()` inserts the content directly for you.  It does not give you an opportunity to modify it before it is inserted.  As such you have two options:

1. You can modify the content after it is inserted, but before it is painted in the `.load()` completion handler.
2. You can switch to `.get()` to get the content as data, then put it into a jQuery object, then modify it using jQuery methods, then insert the modified content into your page yourself.

Here's an example of the second option:

```
$.get("http://<URL>", function(data) {
    var temp = $(data);
    temp.find('#containerTop').remove();
    $('#middle').empty().append(temp);
});
```

Comment: thank you, it works with  $('#middle').html(data).find('#containerTop').remove(); but this removes the element after placing. Can I remove elements bevor data is placed?

Answer (score -3):

`response.find(element).remove()`

This works with me

Comment: thank you. but an error appears after using this: $response is not defined

Comment: `function(html) {
                    var $ajaxFetched = jQuery(html).find("#ajax-fetchable");` also works