# Jquery - Can't remove() from AJAx response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently trying to remove CSS-Tags `<link ..>` and JS-Tags `<script ...>` from an xhtml-file I get by `$.get()`
But as you can see in the attached [firebug output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZROT.png) it doesn't seem to work. There seems to be no change in the temp variable, although `temp.filter('link').remove()` should get the right tags. Is my code not working, or am I just not interpreting the firebug output the right way?

I tried implementing it as mentioned in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26319507/5400948

My code is as follows:

```
$.get("../BaseApplication/user/userList.xhtml", function(data) {
    var temp = $(data);
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(temp.filter('link').remove());
    console.log(temp);
});
```

[firebug output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZROT.png)

Comment: `temp.filter('link').remove()` returns the filtered elements but it does NOT modify the original collection `temp`

Comment: I want to remove all `<link >`Elements, like `<link href="/css/font-awesome.css.xhtml" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` so it should still be `temp.filter('link').remove()`shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting this, because I found a solution which is working for me:

```
$.get("../BaseApplication/user/userList.xhtml", function(data) {
  var temp = $(data);
  temp = temp.not('link').not('script'));
  $('#mainContent').html(temp);
});
```

This removes all `<link ...>` and `<script ...>`Tags from the AJAX-response and replaces everything inside of `<div id="mainConent">`

Comment: how on earth this question and answer both haven't got the votes that they actually deserve? Looking for this and finally found it and fixed my problem!

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was not correct. I've looked and cannot find documentation explaining why this happens. However, this will work:

```
var temp = $('<div>').append($(test)).find('link').remove().end().unwrap();
$('body').append(temp);
```

Basically, this appends the html to a div, searches that div for link elements, removes them, drops back down to the div element, strips the div wrapper off the remaining html, then appends the modified results.

Honestly, I can't find anything explaining this behaviour but, there it is. I hope it helps.

Comment: So you're saying `.filter()` doesn't work with `.remove()`?
In this [example on stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319417/remove-html-elements-from-jquery-ajax-load-response/26319507#26319507), they're using `temp.find('tag').remove()` which seems to work for them.
`.find()` doesn't work for me with `<link ...>`, as the resulting array is empty. But `find('script')` is delivering an array of all `<script ...>`-Tags, but unfortunately still doesn't work with `.remove()`
So is their example wrong?

Comment: That post uses `. find()` not `.filter()`, Ill update with an example

Comment: @TobiasDelp actually, I was not correct before in why this hapens,please see my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your effort. I just found another solution for my problem:
`temp = temp.not('script').not('link');`
This returns the object without the `<link ...>` and `<script ..>` Tags

Comment: Nice, leave the question up though, maybe someone will see it that can better explain why your first attempt doesn't work